How to resolve the: "error: ‘FILE’ has no member named ‘_ptr’" while I try to compile a file in Ubuntu 22.04 wtih Makefile?
I got a new problem over here. I'm trying yo compile a C file which I have a section to read info from a file 'users.txt' using the _ptr pointer from the FILE structure. The main problem is when I try to compile the file I got the next error in the terminal: error: ‘FILE’ has no member named ‘_ptr’, and downside the error I got this: make: *** [Makefile:16: main.o] Error 1
This is the Makefile:
ASM_SOURCE = functions.asm
C_SOURCE = main.c
OBJ_FILES = main.o functions.o

EXEC_RELEASE = main_release.bin
EXEC_DEBUG = main_debug.bin

release: $(OBJ_FILES)
    gcc -o $(EXEC_RELEASE) $(OBJ_FILES)

debug: $(OBJ_FILES)
    gcc -g -o $(EXEC_DEBUG) $(OBJ_FILES)

main.o: $(C_SOURCE)
    gcc -c $(C_SOURCE)

functions.o: $(ASM_SOURCE)
    nasm -f elf64 -o functions.o $(ASM_SOURCE)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_FILES) $(OBJ_FILES) $(EXEC_DEBUG)

This is the C file:
Please ignore the text written in Spanish, I'm coding this with a friend.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LECTURA_COMPLETA 1
#define LECTURA_INCOMPLETA 0

struct Archivos{
    FILE *f1;
    FILE *f2;
    FILE *f3;
};

char** lecturaFile1(struct Archivos file);
char** lecturaFile2(struct Archivos file);
char** lecturaFile3(struct Archivos file);

int main(void)
{
    /// Menu variables
    int MenuUserOn = 1;
    int menu_input, user_input;

    /// User variables
    int number_account, saldoEnCuenta; // Pruebas
    char **users, **pins, **saldos; // Estos buffers tendr�n nuestra informaci�n
    struct Archivos f;

    // Leyendo el contenido de los archivos
    users = lecturaFile1(f);
    pins = lecturaFile2(f);
    saldos = lecturaFile3(f);

    if(users && pins && saldos) // Verificaci�n de entrar al programa
    {
        while(1)
        {
        printf("----------------------- MENU -----------------------\n\n");
        printf("Ingrese el numero con la funcion que desea realizar\n");
        printf("(1) Iniciar operacion\n");
        printf("(2) Cancelar operacion\n= ");
        scanf("%d", &menu_input);

        switch(menu_input)
        {
            case 1:
                MenuUserOn = 1;
                saldoEnCuenta = 2000;
                system("clear");

                printf("Ingrese su numero de cuenta.\n= ");
                scanf("%d",&number_account);

                while(number_account != 1)
                {
                    system("clear");
                    printf("Opcion invalida, ingrese un nombre de usuario valido.\n= ");
                    scanf("%d",&number_account);
                }

                while(MenuUserOn == 1)
                {
                    // Pas� el filtro de seguridad
                    system("clear");
                    printf("----------------------- MENU DE USUARIO -----------------------\n\n");
                    printf("Clave de usuario: %d\n", number_account);
                    printf("Saldo disponible: %d\n\n", saldoEnCuenta);
                    printf("Ingrese el numero de la opcion que desee consultar\n");
                    printf("(1) Depositar\n(2) Retirar\n(3) Transferir\n(4) Cerrar sesion\n= ");
                    scanf("%d", &user_input);

                    switch(user_input)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            sleep(1);
                            system("clear");
                            printf("----------------------- DEPOSITAR -----------------------\n\n");
                            // Futura implementaci�n: Si el saldo es mayor o igual a 10,000. NO DEBE DEPOSITAR
                            sleep(1);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            sleep(1);
                            system("clear");
                            printf("----------------------- RETIRAR -----------------------\n\n");
                            // Futura implementaci�n: Si el saldo es menor o igual a 100. NO DEBE RETIRAR
                            sleep(1);
                            break;

                        case 3:
                            sleep(1);
                            system("clear");
                            printf("----------------------- TRANSFERIR -----------------------\n\n");
                            // Futura implementaci�n: Si el No de cuenta de otro usuario, NO DEBE TRANSFERIR
                            sleep(1);
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            sleep(1);
                            system("clear");
                            sleep(1);
                            printf("----------------------- Sesi�n cerrada exitosamente -----------------------\n\n");
                            sleep(1);
                            system("clear");
                            MenuUserOn = 0; // Cerrando el menu de consultas en la cuenta
                            break;

                        default:
                            printf("Opcion invalida.\n\n");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                sleep(1);
                system("clear");
                sleep(1);
                printf("----------------------- SESION CERRADA EXITOSAMENTE -----------------------\n");
                sleep(1);
                return 0;

            default:
                system("clear");
                printf("Opcion no reconocida.\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("ERROR EN EL SISTEMA, CONTACTE AL TECNICO A CARGO DEL CAJERO");
        sleep(1);
        return 0;
    }
}

/// FUNCIONES DE LECTURA DE ARCHIVOS ////
char** lecturaFile1(struct Archivos file)
{
    file.f1 = fopen("users.txt","r");
    char **users; // Creando buffers de tipo char que apuntar�n hacia
    int n; // Contadores para cada archivo
    char *inicio = NULL; // Punteros para el inicio del archivo
    char *fin = NULL; // Punteros para el final del archivo
    char *linea = NULL;
    char *bufferAuxiliar; // Buffer que nos permitir� guardar la linea
    int offset; // Desplazamiento del archivo
    int flag; // Variable de estado
    int i, j; // Variables para ciclos

    if(file.f1)
    {
        if(getc(file.f1) != EOF) // SETTINGS PARA LEER EL ACHIVO
        {
            //PONER EL CURSOR EN INICIO DE CADA ARCHIVO
            fseek(file.f1, 0, SEEK_SET);

            //OBTENER LA DIRECCION DE INICIO
            inicio = file.f1->_ptr;

            //PONER EL CURSOR EN EL FINAL
            fseek(file.f1, 0, SEEK_END);

            //OBTENER LA CANTIDAD DE BYTE DEL ARCHIVO CON FTELL, RESTAR 1 PARA TENER EL OFFSET
            //ENTRE LA DIRECCION DE INICIO Y LA FINAL
            offset = ftell(file.f1) - 1;

            //OBTENER LA DIRECCION FINAL
            fin = file.f1->_ptr + offset;

            //APUNTAR AL INICIO
            fseek(file.f1, 0, SEEK_SET);

            linea = file.f1 -> _ptr;

            //INDICAR QUE TODAVIA NO SE LEE COMPLETAMENTE EL ARCHIVO
            flag = LECTURA_INCOMPLETA;
        }

        if(linea)
        {
            /// APERTURA DE LECTURA DE INFORMACI�N PARA EL ARCHIVO USERS
            users = calloc(5, sizeof(char*)); // Creando espacio para los usuarios
            flag = LECTURA_INCOMPLETA; // Asignando la bandera a 0
            i = 0; // Rastrear el valor del buffer main
            while(1)
            {
                // Apuntar al primer char
                linea = file.f1 -> _ptr;
                n = 0; // Definiendo el valor de estos en 0

                //CONTAR HASTA QUE ENCUENTRE UN SALTO DE LINEA, FIN DE LINEA, O QUE YA ENCONTR� EL ULTIMO CARACATER DEL ARCHIVO
                while(linea[n] != '\n' && linea[n] != '\0' && (linea+n+1) != fin)
                {
                    n++;
                }
                n+=1;

                bufferAuxiliar = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
                users[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(char)); // Creando espacio en la posici�n i con n longitud de chars

                //COPIAR CARACTER POR CARACTER con FGETC, SE PODRIA USAR FGETS
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    bufferAuxiliar[j] = fgetc(file.f1);
                    users[i][j] = bufferAuxiliar[j]; // Copiando cada char de bufferAuxiliar en Base de datos

                    //CAMBIAR SALTO DE LINEA POR CARACATER VACIO PARA IMPRESION
                    if(bufferAuxiliar[j]=='\n')
                    {
                        bufferAuxiliar[j] = '\0';
                    }
                    if(bufferAuxiliar[j] == EOF)
                    {
                        //INDICAR QUE YA SE LLEGO AL FINAL DEL ARCHIVO
                        flag = LECTURA_COMPLETA;

                        //SUSTITUIR EOF POR CARACTER VACIO PARA IMPRESION
                        bufferAuxiliar[j] = '\0';
                    }
                }
                i++; // Limpiando archivo
                free(bufferAuxiliar); // Limpiando buffer auxiliar

                //TERMINAR DE LEER LINEAS EN EL ARCHIVO
                if(flag == LECTURA_COMPLETA)
                {
                    return users; // Retorno de la informaci�n
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0; // fail
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0; // fail
    }
}

char** lecturaFile2(struct Archivos file)
{
    file.f2 = fopen("pins.txt","r");
    char **pins; // Creando buffers de tipo char que apuntar�n hacia
    int n; // Contadores para cada archivo
    char *inicio = NULL; // Punteros para el inicio del archivo
    char *fin = NULL; // Punteros para el final del archivo
    char *linea = NULL;
    char *bufferAuxiliar; // Buffer que nos permitir� guardar la linea
    int offset; // Desplazamiento del archivo
    int flag; // Variable de estado
    int i, j; // Variables para ciclos

    if(file.f2)
    {
        if(getc(file.f2) != EOF) // SETTINGS PARA LEER EL ACHIVO
        {
            //PONER EL CURSOR EN INICIO DE CADA ARCHIVO
            fseek(file.f2, 0, SEEK_SET);

            //OBTENER LA DIRECCION DE INICIO
            inicio = file.f2->_ptr;

            //PONER EL CURSOR EN EL FINAL
            fseek(file.f2, 0, SEEK_END);

            //OBTENER LA CANTIDAD DE BYTE DEL ARCHIVO CON FTELL, RESTAR 1 PARA TENER EL OFFSET
            //ENTRE LA DIRECCION DE INICIO Y LA FINAL
            offset = ftell(file.f2) - 1;

            //OBTENER LA DIRECCION FINAL
            fin = file.f2 -> _ptr+offset;

            //APUNTAR AL INICIO
            fseek(file.f2, 0, SEEK_SET);

            linea = file.f2 -> _ptr;

            //INDICAR QUE TODAVIA NO SE LEE COMPLETAMENTE EL ARCHIVO
            flag = LECTURA_INCOMPLETA;
        }

        if(linea)
        {
            /// APERTURA DE LECTURA DE INFORMACI�N PARA EL ARCHIVO PINS
            pins = calloc(5, sizeof(char*)); // Creando espacio para los usuarios
            flag = LECTURA_INCOMPLETA; // Asignando la bandera a 0
            i = 0; // Rastrear el valor del buffer main
            while(1)
            {
                // Apuntar al primer char
                linea = file.f2 -> _ptr;
                n = 0; // Definiendo el valor de estos en 0

                //CONTAR HASTA QUE ENCUENTRE UN SALTO DE LINEA, FIN DE LINEA, O QUE YA ENCONTR� EL ULTIMO CARACATER DEL ARCHIVO
                while(linea[n] != '\n' && linea[n] != '\0' && (linea+n+1) != fin)
                {
                    n++;
                }
                n+=1;

                bufferAuxiliar = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
                pins[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(char)); // Creando espacio en la posici�n i con n longitud de chars

                //COPIAR CARACTER POR CARACTER con FGETC, SE PODRIA USAR FGETS
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    bufferAuxiliar[j] = fgetc(file.f2);
                    pins[i][j] = bufferAuxiliar[j]; // Copiando cada char de bufferAuxiliar en Base de datos

                    //CAMBIAR SALTO DE LINEA POR CARACATER VACIO PARA IMPRESION
                    if(bufferAuxiliar[j]=='\n')
                    {
                        bufferAuxiliar[j] = '\0';
                    }
                    if(bufferAuxiliar[j] == EOF)
                    {
                        //INDICAR QUE YA SE LLEGO AL FINAL DEL ARCHIVO
                        flag = LECTURA_COMPLETA;

                        //SUSTITUIR EOF POR CARACTER VACIO PARA IMPRESION
                        bufferAuxiliar[j] = '\0';
                    }
                }
                i++; // Limpiando archivo
                free(bufferAuxiliar); // Limpiando buffer auxiliar

                //TERMINAR DE LEER LINEAS EN EL ARCHIVO
                if(flag == LECTURA_COMPLETA)
                {
                    return pins; // Retorno de la informaci�n
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0; // fail
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Archivo no encontrado\n");
        return 0; // fail
    }
}

char** lecturaFile3(struct Archivos file)
{
    file.f3 = fopen("saldos.txt","r");
    char **saldos; // Creando buffers de tipo char que apuntar�n hacia
    int n; // Contadores para cada archivo
    char *inicio = NULL; // Punteros para el inicio del archivo
    char *fin = NULL; // Punteros para el final del archivo
    char *linea = NULL;
    char *bufferAuxiliar; // Buffer que nos permitir� guardar la linea
    int offset; // Desplazamiento del archivo
    int flag; // Variable de estado
    int i, j; // Variables para ciclos

    if(file.f3)
    {
        if(getc(file.f3) != EOF) // SETTINGS PARA LEER EL ACHIVO
        {
            //PONER EL CURSOR EN INICIO DE CADA ARCHIVO
            fseek(file.f3, 0, SEEK_SET);

            //OBTENER LA DIRECCION DE INICIO
            inicio = file.f3 -> _ptr;

            //PONER EL CURSOR EN EL FINAL
            fseek(file.f3, 0, SEEK_END);

            //OBTENER LA CANTIDAD DE BYTE DEL ARCHIVO CON FTELL, RESTAR 1 PARA TENER EL OFFSET
            //ENTRE LA DIRECCION DE INICIO Y LA FINAL
            offset = ftell(file.f3) - 1;

            //OBTENER LA DIRECCION FINAL
            fin = file.f3 -> _ptr+offset;

            //APUNTAR AL INICIO
            fseek(file.f3, 0, SEEK_SET);

            linea = file.f3 -> _ptr;

            //INDICAR QUE TODAVIA NO SE LEE COMPLETAMENTE EL ARCHIVO
            flag = LECTURA_INCOMPLETA;
        }

        if(linea)
        {
            /// APERTURA DE LECTURA DE INFORMACI�N PARA EL ARCHIVO SALDOS
            saldos = calloc(5, sizeof(char*)); // Creando espacio para los usuarios
            flag = LECTURA_INCOMPLETA; // Asignando la bandera a 0
            i = 0; // Rastrear el valor del buffer main
            while(1)
            {
                // Apuntar al primer char
                linea = file.f3 -> _ptr;
                n = 0; // Definiendo el valor de estos en 0

                //CONTAR HASTA QUE ENCUENTRE UN SALTO DE LINEA, FIN DE LINEA, O QUE YA ENCONTR� EL ULTIMO CARACATER DEL ARCHIVO
                while(linea[n] != '\n' && linea[n] != '\0' && (linea+n+1) != fin)
                {
                    n++;
                }
                n+=1;

                bufferAuxiliar = calloc(n, sizeof(char));
                saldos[i] = calloc(n, sizeof(char)); // Creando espacio en la posici�n i con n longitud de chars

                //COPIAR CARACTER POR CARACTER con FGETC, SE PODRIA USAR FGETS
                for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    bufferAuxiliar[j] = fgetc(file.f3);
                    saldos[i][j] = bufferAuxiliar[j]; // Copiando cada char de bufferAuxiliar en Base de datos

                    //CAMBIAR SALTO DE LINEA POR CARACATER VACIO PARA IMPRESION
                    if(bufferAuxiliar[j]=='\n')
                    {
                        bufferAuxiliar[j] = '\0';
                    }
                    if(bufferAuxiliar[j] == EOF)
                    {
                        //INDICAR QUE YA SE LLEGO AL FINAL DEL ARCHIVO
                        flag = LECTURA_COMPLETA;

                        //SUSTITUIR EOF POR CARACTER VACIO PARA IMPRESION
                        bufferAuxiliar[j] = '\0';
                    }
                }
                i++; // Limpiando archivo
                free(bufferAuxiliar); // Limpiando buffer auxiliar

                //TERMINAR DE LEER LINEAS EN EL ARCHIVO
                if(flag == LECTURA_COMPLETA)
                {
                    return saldos; // Retorno de la informaci�n
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return 0; // fail
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0; // fail
    }
}

I hope y'all guys can help me, I would appreciate a lot.
I tried to use the command -l and -L on the Makefile line where the error appears in terminal.
Example:
C_SOURCE = main.c
main.o: $(C_SOURCE)
    gcc -L stdio. h-c $(C_SOURCE)


Can you please post compilable code?

FILE is an opaque type: this means you cannot portably dereference the FILE * and access its members.  The structure contents is not documented so there is no point trying to access file.f1 -> _ptr.
The code is bogus: it uses hard coded knowledge of the FILE implementation and assumes the file fits in the FILE buffer.  Don't use this code even on the platform it was written for.
After you determine the file length, You can read the file contents with fread and set a null terminator.  Alternately, you can read one line at a time woth fgets()...

I got it, so, what should I do or where should I define the opaque struct so my functions can work with that?

Where do you get the idea that there is a _ptr member in a FILE structure? From what you posted, we cannot even tell what file nor file.f1 are.  You should post a full program so we can try and understand what your intent is even if said program does not compile.

When I access to the definition of stdio.h (in VS Code), in the line 210 to 220 appaers all the members of the FILE structure. I uploaded the original post with the complete C file.

@AdriánRamírez The _ptr looks like an early unix impl. (now from *BSD). linux/glibc is more complex. But, even if you could get the correct name, you do not want to do this. Your idea will fail depending upon the amount of buffer space allocated in the FILE struct. You can get the same effect without needing to do this. Restructure your code to not use this.

@AdriánRamírez You're trying to replicate what you can do easily with fgets. You're "peeking" at the buffer to find the length of the line (i.e. where is the newline). But, then, you're doing fgetc to pull in the data. Anything your "trick" might save (in terms of speed) is lost due to the [slow] fgetc loop.

@AdriánRamírez: VS code is ill advised showing you the internals of a particular implementation of FILE. Do not use this information.  Just use fgetc(), fgets() or fread().


I'm trying yo compile a C file which I have a section to read info from a file 'users.txt' using the _ptr pointer from the FILE structure.

The ISO C Standard does that specify whether FILE has a _ptr member. The code you're writing is incredibly non-portable, you should never be peeking into FILE's internals.
If you want to read data from a file, use fgets()/fscanf()/fread().
